# Task result returning null always

Tags: c#, task

I have Receive method in the class WebSocket

```
public async Task<string> Receive()
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            string response = string.Empty;

            while (_socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                var result = await _socket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), new CancellationToken(false));

                if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                    await _socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
                else
                {
                    response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer).TrimEnd('\0');
                }
            }
            return response;
        }
```

**Calling Receive method from object wb as below:**

```
async Task<string> OnMessageReceive()
            {
                return await Task.Run(() => wb.Receive());
            }
```

Expecting to receive the response but always get null as part of Result.

```
var msg = OnMessageReceive();
Console.WriteLine(msg.Result);
```

Difficult to figure out why Result is not returning string data!.

[Solution (Uploaded to github repo)](https://github.com/gittadesushil/WebSocketClient)

Comment: Why do you have Result at end ( wb.Receive().Result)?  The receive method returns a response without Result.

Comment: Ok. I removed the Result as you told. Still I am getting null. If you look at my Receive method I am returning response explicitly.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your Receive method ? Is it actually returning anything ?

Comment: Yes this line response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer).TrimEnd('\0'); returns string response.

Comment: Are you getting to the response in the code or just doing the CloseAsync?  How long is it taking to get the null?

Comment: Yes I am getting to the response and returning specifically. Note I return string not Task<string> and that compiles.

Comment: Why are you using Task.Run? Just await the Receive method.

Comment: The code you posted cannot possibly have that behavior. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @StephenCleary I uploaded the solution on github repo. Could please have look.

Comment: The [mcve] should be inside your question. Not on github.

Comment: @mjwills I thought it will be easy to get answer. From yesterday I am trying different ways to get value from Task<string> and It should. I am not expert on Task, I am designing this by reading online materials.

Comment: I downloaded your repro, but it doesn't repro. The test passes just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you are calling a async method without await so it won't wait for complete the execution of your code

```
async Task<string> OnMessageReceive(){....}

var msg = OnMessageReceive(); // you need to use await key word to call this method
```

Comment: `msg.Result` will block and wait for the completion of the task

Comment: This is what happening with me!.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of changes and you should be good to go.

**First -**

```
async Task<string> OnMessageReceive()
{
     return await wb.Receive();
}
```

**Second -**

```
var msg = await OnMessageReceive();
Console.WriteLine(msg);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer :)

The problem was with while loop. Below line of code was getting executed in loop and while second call ReceiveAsync method get re-execute and loop exits with re-initialization of response variable.

```
var result = await _socket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), new CancellationToken(false));
```

Also I refer below resource:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types

Comment: I don't understand why there is down vote? I just posted my observation. I found answer later is that my mistake!.